# Fail to transfer the list in data frame to numpy array with python-pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

For a data frame `df`:

```
name       list1                    list2
a          [1, 3, 10, 12, 20..]     [2, 6, 23, 29...]
b          [2, 10, 14, 3]           [4, 7, 8, 13...]
c          []                       [98, 101, 200]
...
```

I want to transfer the `list1` and `list2` to `np.array` and then `hstack` them. Here is what I did:

```
df.pv = df.apply(lambda row: np.hstack((np.asarray(row.list1), np.asarray(row.list2))), axis=1)
```

And I got such an error:

```
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (138493, 175), indices imply (138493, 4)
```

Where `138493==len(df)`

Please note that some value in `list1` and `list2` is empty list, `[]`. And the length of list are different among rows. Do you know what is the reason how can I fix the problem? Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

When I just try to convert one list to array:

```
df.apply(lambda row: np.asarray(row.list1), axis=1)
```

An error also occurs:

```
ValueError: Empty data passed with indices specified.
```

Comment: can you provide a reproducible input?

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel Thanks for your reply! Isn't the sample above reproducible?

Comment: @user5779223 How did you create you dataframe, that's what he meant

Comment: @MMF I read in a data set and convert it to the form like this. Indeed I still don't know what information you need?

Comment: share with us the code where you create `df`. `df = ?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your apply function is *almost* correct. All you have to do - convert the output of the `np.hstack()` function back to a python list.

```
df.apply(lambda row: list(np.hstack((np.asarray(row.list1), np.asarray(row.list2)))), axis=1)
```

The code is shown below (including the df creation):

```
df = pd.DataFrame([('a',[1, 3, 10, 12, 20],[2, 6, 23, 29]),
                   ('b',[2, 10, 1.4, 3],[4, 7, 8, 13]),
                   ('c',[],[98, 101, 200])],
                   columns = ['name','list1','list2'])

df['list3'] = df.apply(lambda row: list(np.hstack((np.asarray(row.list1), np.asarray(row.list2)))), axis=1)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
0              [1, 3, 10, 12, 20, 2, 6, 23, 29]
1    [2.0, 10.0, 1.4, 3.0, 4.0, 7.0, 8.0, 13.0]
2                          [98.0, 101.0, 200.0]
Name: list3, dtype: object
```

If you want a numpy array, the only way I could get it to work is:

```
df['list3'] = df['list3'].apply(lambda x: np.array(x))

print(type(df['list3'].ix[0]))
Out[] : numpy.ndarray
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but what if I wanted it be a numpy array?